# Return Records where value = x SSRS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a report structured as such

```
Value | Date | Value Substring
xxxa  | date | a
xxxb  | date | b
xxxb  | date | b
xxxb  | date | b
xxxc  | date | c
xxxc  | date | c
```

I want a drop-down list containing all substring values (a, b, c) and then when i select a substring value from the list it returns all records where the substring value matches.

I cannot work out for the life of me how to do it!

Any help would be greatly appreciated
Thanks,
Gareth

Comment: Add a parameter to the report and then add a filter to your data set (or table).  Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: got it, thanks buddy, just wasn't sure how to do it all, brand new to SSRS

Comment: That only works for 1 substring though, i need to be able to have a choice

Comment: Check "Allow multiple values" in the report parameter.  You'll need to either hard-code possible values or create a dataset that will select them from existing data.

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a parameter (drop down) driven by

```
select distinct [value string]
from [wherever you're getting the above data from]
order by [value string] asc
```

Then use the select value of the drop down parameter to filter the query... either at the dataset level or at the matrix (presentation) level. Dataset level would be more efficient.

Comment: The substring values have been created using a switch expression, does the above still apply?

Comment: If you share what you're doing under the hood... we can help better.... from the look of it.  If Value is truly XXXa then you can do select distinct right(value,1) from ...